# Regarding an integer being a sum of three primes...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I knew that every even number up to $4 \times 10^{14} $ is the sum of two primes, roughly how many primes would I need to find in order to show that every odd number up to $10^{22}$ is the sum of three primes? Why does this make efficient primality testing important?

Well... if we know that every even number up to $4 \times 10^{14} $ is the sum of two primes, then if we add $3$ to each even number then we get every odd number up to $4 \times 10^{14}+1 $ as a sum of three primes. We can add primes bigger than $3$, say $5$ or $7$ to the even numbers verified to be the sum of two primes, but eventually we would get gaps. I am not sure how we can systematically extend the first assertion about twin primes to the second assertion about prime triplets, and roughly how many primes would I actually need? I am also not really sure about the last question about primality testing.

Comment: To answer the last question : If we have a number near $10^{22}$ , then one of the primes in a representation must necessarily exceed $3\cdot 10^{21}$. Trial division would become very time consuming since we will need many of primes in this range. If we can assume Goldbach only to the mentioned range, I guess this won't help much. I think we need many primes exceeding $3\cdot 10^{21}$ to approve the second claim with just brute force.

Comment: @Peter good point, but I think I need to semi-derive the second assertion from the first assertion somehow to alleviate much of the brute force effort.

Answer (score 1):

Some experiments:

We may use primes generators to find some odd number generators which are the sum of three primes. For example take prime generators:

$2x+1$

$4x-1$

$6x-1$

$n=12x-1$ is an odd number which is or can be written as the sum of three primes. For example:

$x=2\rightarrow 5+7+11=23$

$x=3\rightarrow 7+11+17=35$

$x=6\rightarrow 13+23+35=11+23+37=71$

So we may conclude that a family of odd numbers of the for $12x-1$ are the sum of three primes.
We may also use other prime generators ; for example primes of the form $30k+r$; $r=1, 7, 11,13, 17, 19, 23, 29$ There can be $\binom {7}{3}=35$ forms of odd number generators. Fro example:

$30k+1$

$30k+7$

$30k+11$

So odd number of the form $90k+19$ are the sum of three primes. this is one form  out of the  35 forms of odd numbers of the form  $90k+R$. So in a computer program we can first check if an arbitrary odd number has above forms or not. Clearly there would be gaps which  may indicate not all odd numbers are the sum of three primes.

Update: some rough estimations:

Suppose all primes are of the form $30k+r$. Let's take $k=1\rightarrow 1000$, then we have $35\times 1000=35000$ numbers which are the sum of three primes. the smallest one and its related primes is from $n=90k+19$:

$(n, p_1, p_2, p_3)=(109, 31, 37, 41)$

and the largest one resulting from $90k+71=(30k+19)+(30k+23)+(30k+29)$ is:

$(n, p_1, p_2, p_3)=(90071, 29, 73, 59)$

Note that $p_1=49-20=29$, $p_2=53+20=73$,that is n can be written as the sum of three distinct primes. The even number next to $90071$ is $90072$ and number of odd numbers within range $29$ to $90071$ is:

$\frac{90072}2-25=45011$

So the ratio of n on total odd numbers is:

$\frac {35000}{45011}\approx 0.77\approx 78$%

Unless we reject the theorem of $30k+r$ or the hypotheses that all odd numbers are the sum of three primes.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach require that $2x+1,4x-1,6x-1$ are simultaneously prime (for the same $x$) ? Although (probably) infinite many $x$ do the job, I think not many in the range the author needs will do. And even then, we only would have covered the $12x-1$ - case. The same issue should occur for the other approach.

Comment: @Peter, Hello Peter. I mean All odd generators must be considered especially $n=90 k+R$. This set is definitely sum of three primes. we can find all such odd numbers to see in a certain range how many percent they fill.I think this method take less times than conventional methods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this result is useful to you, but if the generalized Riemann hypothesis is true then every odd number greater than $2 \times 10^{12}$ can be written as the sum of three primes.

The generalized Riemann hypothesis says that:

Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character and its complex number such that $L(\chi, s)=0$, if the real part of $s$ is included between 0 and 1, then it is equal to 1/2. note that in the case $\chi(n)=1$, leads to the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Oooo... sounds interesting but too advanced for me! :)

Comment: Seems that the author wants to verify the range upto $10^{22}$ directly and this partial result even needs the truth of the generalized Riemann hypothesis. If it is true we can replace $2\cdot 10^{12}$ by $7$ anyway since the Goldbach conjecture has been checked far beyond this mark and this implies that every odd number from $7$ until there allows a representation.